# How to preserve white spaces in angular js while binding text

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I want to remove only spaces on the left and right of a string, not in between. So, if there are 2 spaces in between the string they should be preserved. While using the below code, all spaces get preserved. Does anybody face this problem. How do I fix it?

`<pre>{{courses.ProductTitle}}</pre>`

Comment: you can use trim() method. create a function that uses trim in the controller and call that method in your html. Exemple: `removeSpace(courses.ProductTitle)` where removeSpace is a method in the controller that uses trim().

Comment: this doesnot work . i can still see leading ,trailing spaces . if i dont use pre it works fine all spaces are gone but  if there are more than one space between the words, it also removes them on UI. if u inspect the element u can still see 2 spaces between words in string but on UI only one space is shown. on UI also i want to preserve more than one space between words if there is any.

Comment: if i have a string "i am going to   school" . it should display as it is . what is happening is on  UI there is only one space between words . but if u inspect that element it shows extra spaces before "school".  i want to preserve these extra whitespaces on UI as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
<pre>{{courses.ProductTitle.trim()}}</pre>
```

Comment: this doesnot work . i can still see leading ,trailing spaces . if i dont use pre it works fine all spaces are gone but  if there are more than one space between the words, it also removes them on UI. if u inspect the element u can still see 2 spaces between words in string but on UI only one space is shown. on UI also i want to preserve more than one space between words if there is any.

Comment: if i have a string "i am going to   school" . it should display as it is . what is happening is on  UI there is only one space between words . but if u inspect that element it shows extra spaces before "school".  i want to preserve these extra whitespaces on UI as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** As of 2015, all major browsers (including IE>=9) support String.prototype.trim(). This means that for most use cases simply doing courses.ProductTitle.trim() is the best way of achieving what the question asks.

```
//For (IE 8 and down)
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

The new **Safari** (5), **Chrome**(5), **Firefox**(3.6) and **Opera**(10.5) all support a native String trim method. Thats being the case, I'd assign a method to String.prototype, if it does not exist.

```
String.prototype.trim = String.prototype.trim || function trim() { 
      return this.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''); 
};
```

Performance wise if you want to handle long strings exceptionally fast in all browsers.

```
function trimString (str) {
    str = str.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (/\S/.test(str.charAt(i))) {
            str = str.substring(0, i + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

**Refrences**
[Steven Levithan analyzed many different implementation of trim in Javascript in terms of performance.](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript)

Comment: if i have a string "i am going to   school" . it should display as it is . what is happening is on  UI there is only one space between words . but if u inspect that element it shows extra spaces before "school".  i want to preserve these extra whitespaces on UI as well.

Comment: Have you tried to write a function to do that and that function should `return YOURSTRING.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');` here, YOURSTRING is the string "i am going to school". As you are using <pre> element hope this should work

Comment: try this `replace(^\\s+|\\s+$, '')`

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out the answer . in pre tags i was having spaces that it was preserving . so instead 
      `<pre>   variable  </pre>`
 it should be 
`<pre>variable</pre>` 
then only spaces inside the varibale no matter how many will be preserved.